# Attached Behavior property not being set by binding in UWP

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml, attachedbehaviors

I created a behavior class with a dependency property that I want to attach to a control in my view (XAML). I am using MVVM and I need to set this attached property by binding it to a property in my ViewModel, but it does not get set. Here is a simplified version of what I want to do:

**Behavior Class:**

```
public static class TestBehavior
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomeStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SomeString", typeof(string), typeof(TestBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(""));

    public static string GetSomeString(DependencyObject o)
    {
        return (string)o.GetValue(SomeStringProperty);
    }

    public static void SetSomeString(DependencyObject o, string value)
    {
        o.SetValue(SomeStringProperty, value);
    }

}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewModelProperty}" local:TestBehavior.SomeString="{Binding ViewModelProperty}" />
```

The "Text" property of the TextBlock binds correctly, but the "SomeString" property of the behavior does not.

Interestingly - if I "hard code" the behavior property to a value it does get set. For example:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TestValue}" local:TestBehavior.SomeString="Foo" /> <!-- This Works -->
```

Any ideas why the binding to the behavior property does not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you expect the attached behaviour to do?

Are you determining that the attached property is/isn't working by setting a breakpoint on the `GetSomeString`/`SetSomeString` methods? If so, this won't work with binding as the Get/Set methods aren't called when binding is used.

If you want to react when the attached property changes irrespective of whether it's via binding or not then use the `PropertyChangedCallback` of the `PropertyMetadata` specified in the `Register` call.

Comment: That is exactly what I did (using break points). I added the Callback method and it does execute on the binding. Any idea why the Get/Set methods does not get executed when using bindings?

Comment: It's just the way the binding infrastructure works with dependency properties (normal or attached). I believe it's some form of internal optimisation.

Comment: I also believe the `GetSomeString` method is just a common pattern for making it easier for your code to access the property. The platform just sets the values when you bind.